# How to get the first occurrence of value with the matching number from multiple sets

Tags: xslt, position, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have request comes with multiple elements where I need the first occurrence of the where data_type="3". Hence there could be multiple values comes as 0,2,3,4 in random.

When I tried to put the below Xpath function it's returning the all values where data_type='3'

```
<xsl:value-of select="/process/TransactionType/data_xml/transaction/sub_documents/transactionLine[@data_type='3']/Ref"/>
```

Full input and output code click here  [code snippet](http://xsltransform.net/94Acsmc)

How I can get the one value instead all values.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with XPath if `exp` gives you a sequence of values and you want the first use e.g. `(exp)[1]` i.e. `(/process/TransactionType/data_xml/transaction/sub_documents/transactionLine[@data_type='3']/Ref)[1]`.

Comment: Quick and fast response Martin. Thanks a lot it's working